# Update lists in dictionary based on another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a dictionary with lists as values and a seperate list:

```
myDict = {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31, 34], 3: [], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], 5: [], 6: [10, 20, 24]}

myList = [1, 34, 10]
```

How can I remove values from the lists in myDict, if they match the values in myList?

So for the example dictionary I expect in the end a dictionary like this:

```
myDict = {0: [0, 2], 1: [], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31], 3: [], 4: [0, 2, 3, 4, 7], 5: [], 6: [20, 24]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> myDict = {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31, 34], 3: [], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], 5: [], 6: [10, 20, 24]}
>>> myList = [1, 34, 10]
>>> {x:[z for z in y if z not in myList] for x,y in myDict.items()}
{0: [0, 2], 1: [], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31], 3: [], 4: [0, 2, 3, 4, 7], 5: [], 6: [20, 24]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make `myList` a set, and use a dict and list comprehension combo:

```
mySet = set(myList)

myDict = {k: [i for i in v if i not in mySet] for k, v in myDict.items()}
```

Using a set makes this more efficient, as the `in` membership test is a lot faster for sets than it is for lists.

Answer (score 0):

This answer also work:

```
updatedDict = {k:list(set(v) - set(myList)) for k, v in myDict.items()}
```